# saving to .doc file table

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to save some text and values in a doc file and put them in a table inside that doc file ?
I have like a shopping list with a column for product name,one for quantity and one for price.
I'm currently using this to save my files to a doc but they are all messy,they can't be aligned(most of the times the product name,quantity and price vary in text lenght) so i figure putting them in a table is a good way to make sure they are arranged nicely.

Or is there a way to format my text,to put them on columns ?
I hope you understand what i mean,if not,let me know.

```
File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/InterSRL");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, "myData.doc");

    try {
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
        for (int n = 0; n < allpret.size() - 1; n++) {
            if (cant[n] != Float.toString(0)
                    && pret[n] != Float.toString(0)) {
                String myFormat = "%-10s %-10s %-10s%n";
                pw.println(String.format(myFormat, prod[n], cant[n],
                        pret[n]));
            }

        }
        pw.println((String.format("Total: %.2f", totaltest)));
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        f.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(TAG,
                "******* File not found. Did you"
                        + " add a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the   manifest?");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the **Apache POI**. Take a look [here](http://poi.apache.org/).

> In short, you can read and write MS Excel files using Java. In addition, you can read and write MS Word and MS PowerPoint files using Java. Apache POI is your Java Excel solution (for Excel 97-2008). We have a complete API for porting other OOXML and OLE2 formats and welcome others to participate.

[This](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html) is the *Java API to Handle Microsoft Word Files* . Hope it helps.

Comment: A bit hard for my current level(beginner with no programming background) but i'll take a look and try and understand,hehe.Thanks !

Comment: To make things easier...: http://tkgospodinov.com/writing-microsoft-word-documents-in-java-with-apache-poi-part-2-creating-tables/

Comment: Is it possible to save to external storage with Apache POI ? Can't find anything about that anywhere